# Gerar token a partir de string e verificar token gerado

Tags: php, laravel

Basicamente, preciso de algo que funcione parecido com `$hash = Hash::make('string')` e `Hash::check('string', $hash)` mas que não produza um resultado tão grande quanto (60 caracteres).

> ou `$hash = password_hash('string')` e `password_verify('string', $hash)` com PHP puro

Como gerar um "token" a partir de uma string e depois verificar se o "token" gerado corresponde à string geradora?

Comment: Por que você não quer uma hash com 60 caracteres? É muito mais seguro que o md5, cada execução gera uma hash diferente, é eficiente e testável. 60 caracteres não afeta o desempenho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já tentou utilizar `md5`? Ele gerará uma string de 32 caracteres

Veja:

```
echo md5('joãozinho'); // 'a7199fb05606b0d193d79a2dd6c2b537'
```

Para a verificação:

```
 $codigo = 'a7199fb05606b0d193d79a2dd6c2b537';

 var_dump(md5('joãozinho') == $codigo); // True
```

Não sei se essa é uma boa idéia, mas já vi muitas pessoas utilizando o `md5` com um `substr` para reduzir esse número de caracteres do `md5`.

```
  substr(md5('joãozinho'), 0, 8); //Imprime: 'a7199fb0'
```